# Not able to run correct file on Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to run a Flask app with the file name "application.py" by using the command "Flask run".

But when I do that, it runs my older Flask app with the file name "app.py". So, how can I run "application.py"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the environment variable `FLASK_APP` is set to "application.py"

```
export FLASK_APP=application.py
flask run
```

Comment: $ Flask run
 * Serving Flask app "application.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

In localhost, it still shows old app.py file